# Span and linear independence of four vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

For every $u,v,t,w \in \mathbb{R}^3$, is it necessarily true that

1. $\mathbb{R}^3 = \{u,v,t,w\}$
2. $t \in \operatorname{Sp}\{u,v,w\}$
3. $\{u,v,t,w\}$ is linearly dependent

My answers:

> For 1: Not necessarily true, gave a counterexample.
>
> For 2: Yup, if I have more than 3 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ they are linearly dependent. Thus every vector can be written as a combination of other vectors. (Didn't phrase it well, hope you understood me)
>
> For 3. Yup, I explained already. More than 3 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ - must be linearly dependent.

Opinions?

Comment: Is the third one $\{u, v, w, t\}$? Because your answer says "more than $3$", but in the question there're only three vectors.

Comment: You are wrong about 2 and 3.

Comment: Also, your answer to the second one is not correct. Consider $u = (1\ 0\ 0), v = 2u, w = 3u, t = (0\ 0\ 1)$.

Comment: In 3. there are not more than 3 vectors. In 2. sure they are linearly dependent, but that doesn't mean every vector can be written as a combination of the others. For example, take $u=v=w=0$

Comment: To add to what Peter said, "linearly dependent" only means "at least one vector can be written as a linear combination of the others" $-$ it does *not* mean "*each* vector can be written as a linear combination of the others".

Comment: Edited (3.), and you guys are right about (2.) Thanks, solved.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS: Why don't you write it up as an answer?

Comment: u can write ;) ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is false. Suppose that u = 2t = 3v = 4w.

(2) is false. Suppose that u =  3v = 4w.

(3) is true. You cam't have more than n linearly independent vectors in an n-dimensional space.